# Returning sum of column for filtered data, without filter

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the sum of a column (TSQFT in the screenshot) that is part of a data set, which would be filtered based on multiple criteria using cell references ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Ybx.jpg)). I don't want to use excel's regular filter as it's a hassle to change the settings and I'd like it to be done in a more automated way.

I've tried {SUMIF} and {SUMIFS} but those do not work as a filter - i.e. for a row to be {TRUE}, the numbers have to be in the same order as that specified in the criteria list {5-7-2} ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW6Ez.jpg)).

Would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:
Make 3 column of =IF(OR(C3=$C$10;C3=$D$10;C3=$E$10);1;0) formulas, one more column for a sum of this 3 column and a sumif based of the sum values

if the sum is 3 then the value is good.

This maybe the worst solution for this but as long as it can help, it can be developed into something better.

Comment: Thanks Peter! It's a bit lengthy but it works - never thought it'd be that simple.

Comment: The pleasure is mine.